# Add drop down list to dynamically created workbook with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I am using a macro to create a temporary sheet in my workbook, populate a bunch of cells on that sheet with data, export that sheet to a new workbook and close the new workbook.

This all works fine. What I am trying to do is add a drop down list to the temporary sheet (and, hence, new workbook) which holds the list of cell values that were added to said sheet. So I googled how to do this and came across this code:

```
Sub main()

'replace "J2" with the cell you want to insert the drop down list
With Range("J2").Validation
.Delete
'replace "=A1:A6" with the range the data is in.
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
Operator:= xlBetween, Formula1:="=Sheet1!A1:A6"
.IgnoreBlank = True
.InCellDropdown = True
.InputTitle = ""
.ErrorTitle = ""
.InputMessage = ""
.ErrorMessage = ""
.ShowInput = True
.ShowError = True
End With
End Sub
```

I incorporated that into my project, made the necessary reference changes, and tried it out, but when I open the new workbooks the drop down menu is not there. Any suggestions as to how to get this to work?

Comment: Is the active sheet `Sheet1`? Even if  not, are there any data in the range `Sheet1!A1:A6`?

Comment: Yep. It is the activesheet and the cells do have data.

Comment: Please, try the next testing code line (place it in the first line): `Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Name, ActiveSheet.CodeName: Stop`. What does it return in `Immediate Window`when the code stops on this line?

Comment: If the new workbook has only 1 sheet are the drop down list values in A1:A6 on that sheet ?

Comment: The code preceding what you've posted would be useful here.

Comment: `Range("J2").Validation` references the _active sheet_ when you run the code - you should use an explicit reference like e.g. wsTemp.Range("J2") where wsTemp is the sheet you added before. Furthermore: you have to copy Sheet1 as well to the new workbook - as you take the validation list values from there. Copy this sheet before you copy the temporary sheet - to be on the safe side.

Comment: @Ike worked like a charm!

Comment: Perfect. I will paste the comment as answer - then it is clear that your question is solved. Please accept it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range("J2").Validation` references the active sheet when you run the code - you should use an explicit reference like e.g. wsTemp.Range("J2") where wsTemp is the sheet you added before.

Furthermore: you have to copy Sheet1 as well to the new workbook - as you take the validation list values from there. Copy this sheet before you copy the temporary sheet - to be on the safe side.